# Timestamp format not showing different values

Tags: java

I am trying to print out a list of dates/times from a .dat file with the code snippet below, but it always has the same output and I don't know why.

```
SimpleDateFormat TimeStampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:dd:hh:mm:ss:");
long measurement = 0;       


for (i=0; i<MeasurementLength; i++ ){
    databyte = ReadFilterInputPort();
    measurement = measurement | (databyte & 0xFF);  
   if (i != MeasurementLength-1)    
        measurement = measurement << 8;             
} // for

TimeStampA.setTimeInMillis(measurementA);   
System.out.println(measurementA);
System.out.printf("%-22s\n",TimeStampFormat.format(TimeStampA.getTime()));
```

For example, the output of a few lines is:

(input)
1300828035071

(output)
2011:22:05:07:15

(input)    1300828035073

(output) 2011:22:05:07:15

Am I doing something wrong or would this be the correct output for the given input?

Comment: measurementA is a long if that makes a difference

Comment: What about creating a `Date` object e.g. `new Date(measurementA)` and then format it as you like with `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: show `TimeStampFormat#format` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code

```
   try {
            long measureA = System.currentTimeMillis();// You can assign your exact date which is in long format

            Date date = new Date(measureA); 

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz"); 

            System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); 

            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd yyyy"); 

            System.out.println(sdf.format(date));

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

You can change format string according to your need

Comment: That has the same result as mine. Problem is I don't know what the date/times are supposed to be but it seems odd they are all the same when measurementA is slightly different each time. Could it be that it's just too small a change to register?

Comment: I am not getting you clearly. Let me ask question you are getting time in a long format and you are storing long date in variable measurementA. Am i right? or you are not sure in which format you will get the date?

Comment: you are correct. I get it as a long, then store it in measurementA.

Comment: I have modified my code see. I have initialized measurementA variable with current time. You need to change the initialization according to your need. Assign your incoming date to variable and thats it.